# Linux bash: exec programm from terminal, return to terminal after it was closed

Tags: bash, vim, configuration, config, urxvt

I would like to use the mouse features of `gvim`, but have it behave as normal `vim` otherwise. For that, I have added the line `set guioptions=` in my .gvimrc .

I could make an alias to `gvim` (mapping it to `exec gvim`), so that when I open `gvim` from a terminal, it appears to open in the same window.

Is there any way to go back to the starting terminal when I close `gvim`? (like when you close `vim`)

Comment: You don't necessarily need `gvim` to use the mouse. See `:help mouse`.

Comment: ah, cool, I didn't know that was possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:set mouse=a` in `vim` did the trick.